# Is this possible to pass dynamic elements in HTTP body in Object repository from Data Files?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, katalon-studio

[image: Is this possible to pass dynamic elements in HTTP body in Object repository from Data Files??]

Can anyone help me out this situation, please?

Answer (score 0):

It is available since `Katalon Studio` 5.4. Please check it here: https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/Parameterize+a+Web+Service+object

[image]